# Monitor blinking

Tags: 10.04, monitor, flicker

I have Ubuntu 10.04, my laptop is ASUS k50ij, intel duo t3000, 2gb ram, 320 HDD, intel gma 4500M video card.

My problem is that a couple days ago my monitor had start blinking for a few seconds. Then it stops and begins the same behaviour let's say in next 2 hours. What am i missing here?

Another funny problem is that when i give more or less brightness to monitor the pop up window shows and giving "Power information: Laptop battery is charged". When my brightness is lower the blinking increases and vice versa.

thx for help

Comment: I have the very same problem, with Ubunto 10.04 on NEC Versa laptop...

Comment: What if the problem is in electrical installation or electrical dividers? Because when i had my laptop in other place the blinking was enormous but at my home i didn't noticed it yet.

Comment: No, i was wrong. It started again. So electrical installation doesn't have anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't that nice if you have a laptop.

I've been working on a nice big expensive IPS panel, and it started blinking if I powered it off. So as longs as it only went down in Stand-by I was fine, but if I ever pulled the power cord more than once a week it would start to blink.

This has been consistent for 5 years now..

Comment: Hi. Yes, i have laptop and it is really annoying. First time i noticed it it was few days ago when i move laptop to my girlfriend. Then the whole mess started. The blinking is not consistent - sometimes blinks for minutes, other times nothing for hours.